# Redirect router in redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

i wan't to know. Possible to redirect router to some component in redux reducer ?

eg:

```
 case SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, push('/some')};
```

i'm using react-router, react-router-redux.

Answer (score 4):

You should only use the reducer switches to modify the redux state. Anything else like redirecting should only be done in your actions, before you dispatch.

If you are using redux-thunk, you could do something like this:

```
export function myAction(data, history) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: SUCCESS,
            data,
        }).then((response) => {
            history.push("/some")
        });
    };
}
```

Make sure you pass in `this.props.history` when calling your action.

Answer (score 1):

Reducers must be pure functions which means you cannot redirect directly from the state.

To achieve this functionality try using [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Comment: i'm using redux thunk just don't know how figure out with this

Comment: The best way to handle this is to dispatch the action in action handler. You can use store.dispatch() to do that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this could be possible from the reducer, but another thing you could do is. Have a property in the state, to handle the routes, you want to redirect to so that for any action that requires you redirect the user, set that property to the route of your choosing. But I don't see a reason to do this, and what problem are you trying to solve